# How can I control Gigabyte Aorus 7 laptop backlit keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, brightness

I have just bought a Gigabyte Aorus 7 SB laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.10.

The laptop has an RGB backlit keyboard. It comes with Windows 10 and an a windows app to change backlight colours and brightness. I am trying to control the backlit keyboard to dim it or turn it off then be able to turn it on again when required.

When I install Ubuntu the keyboard was backlit a very bright blue colour. I messeda round with a bunch of xset led combinations but they did not do anything with the Led lighting.

I tried used xset led off and a variety of other xset combo's such as xset -led 3 (and every number up to 32).

I ended up booting into Windows again and using the app provided to change the colour and dim the keyboard. But I'd like to control it from within Ubuntu.

Has anyone had any success with this laptop?

I can't even figure out what the keyboard device is.

```
   marty@marty-aorus:~/Videos$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. XPG SX8200 Pro PCIe Gen3x4 M.2 2280 Solid State Drive (rev 03)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
0d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
         

marty@marty-aorus:~/Videos$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:2620 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 2620
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b685 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab28 Seagate RSS LLC Seagate Backup Plus Portable 5TB SRD00F1
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
marty@marty-aorus:~/Videos$
```

Every answer here for other laptops all revolve around using xset but it simply does not work for this laptop!